# Cannot get response in ajax success

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My AJAX code is below. In this i cannot get the response from server side C# code. But there is no issues with my server side code ( I have checked it by debugging ).  From server side i am returning string to this ajax.

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"]' +"provider/GetState",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {CountryId: Country_Id },
        success: function (data) {

        alert(data);

        }
    });
```

Server side code is below

```
          public string GetState(string CountryId)
    {
       int i= Convert.ToInt32(CountryId);
       var Details = objUserAccount.SP_Getstate(i).ToList();
       if(Details.Count>0)
       {
         return "Success";
       }
       else
       {
         return "False";
       }

    }
```

Comment: whether the success handler is getting called...

Comment: post your server action. Try writing an error call back and see if its getting executed.

Comment: put a `debugger` inside in your success handler and check whether it is calling or not. And its always better to have error handler also

Comment: Ya sure @MairajAhmad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Add datatype in your ajax request like this`, if datatype is not matched with received data from server then the ajax error will call instead of success

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: '@System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"]'+  NSSCTProvider/GetState",
contentType: 'application/json',
dataType: "json",
data: {CountryId: Country_Id },
success: function (data) {

alert(data);

},

error: function(data){ 

   alert("Error occured");
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"]'+  NSSCTProvider/GetState",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {CountryId: Country_Id },
    success: function (data) {

    alert(data);

    },

error: function(data){ 

       alert("Error occured");
}
});
```

Either one of the success or failure call back will be initiated if the request is made from this snippet. Might be a server issue, most probably. And make sure that this is the code snippet getting executed. Happens to me all the time.

Comment: I have checked my server side script. It is perfectly working. I am missing something in my client side code.